# Does uniform integrability imply a subsequence that convergences almost surely?

Tags: analysis

Assume $f_n(x)$ is a sequence of uniformly integrable functions on $[0,T]$.Is there a subsequence of $f_n(x)$ that converges to some function $f$ almost surely, i.e. $f_{n_k}(x)$ is a subsequence of $f_n(x)$ such that $f_{n_k}(x) \to f(x)$ a.e.?

Remark: the defintion of the uniform integrability is :
$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sup_{n} \int_{\{x\in[0,T]\hspace{1pt}: f_n (x) \ge N\}} f_n(x) dx = 0$$

I tried to solve it by proving  it by convergence in measure, but I cannot work it out because I am not sure it has the property of convergence in $L^1$ mutually. Could you please help me ?

If there isn't such a property, could you give me a counterexample?

Comment: this has been asked before and the answer is no, see here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4462696/does-uniform-integrability-imply-almost-sure-convergence-of-a-subsequence